# Unicode programming problems, php outputting raw code

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a mysql database set as utf-8, and csv data set as utf-8, delimited by semicolons and enclosed by double quotes.

The data Is seemingly imported fine, when doing a direct dump from the database.
However when attempting to display one of the fields containing html by echoing out in PHP, part of the html code is displayed instead of the link text. Firefox sees the page as utf-8, so that is not the problem.

this is a direct dump of the record of which contains the html field i am trying to output. It appears that the html is not finishing correctly perhaps.

```
ARTICLE_NO  ARTICLE_NAME    SUBTITLE    CURRENT_BID START_PRICE BID_COUNT   QUANT_TOTAL QUANT_SOLD  ACCESSSTARTS    ACCESSENDS  ACCESSORIGIN_END    USERNAME    BEST_BIDDER_ID  FINISHED    WATCH   BUYITNOW_PRICE  PIC_URL PRIVATE_AUCTION AUCTION_TYPE    ACCESSINSERT_DATE   ACCESSUPDATE_DATE   CATEGORY    CATPATH ARTICLE_DESC    COUNTRYCODE LOCATION    CONDITIONS  REVISED PAYPAL_ACCEPT   PRE_TERMINATED  SHIPPING_TO FEE_INSERTION   FEE_FINAL   FEE_LISTING PIC_XXL PIC_DIASHOW PIC_COUNT   ITEM_SITE_ID    STARTS  ENDS    ORIGIN_END
220288560247    Ed Hardy Herren Shirt Rock & Roll Weiss XXL Neu & OVP       0.00    49.00   0   1   0   1.10.2008 16:22:09  6.10.2008 16:22:09  6.10.2008 16:22:09  fashionticker1  0   1   0   59.00   http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/13895964e.jpg   0   1   6.10.2008 16:21:47  6.10.2008 16:28:31  32315   0   <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bitte ÃƒÂ¤ndern Sie im eigenen Interesse nichts an diesem Code! ++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Das kann massive Feggggggghldarstellungen ihrer Auktion zur Folge haben! +++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Ihr Supreme Team +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n\t\n<br>\n<br>\n<style type="text/css">\n<!--\n#doc {\n height: 577px;\n width: 989px;\n position: relative;\n top: 10px;\n left: 0px;\n background-color: #ffffff;\n border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;\n z-index:1;\n margin: 0px;\n padding: 0px;\n clear: none;\n float: none;\n}\n#doc2 {\n line-height: 30px;\n width: 989px;\n position: relative;\n top: 10px;\n left: 20px;\n background-color: #ffffff;\n margin: 0px;\n padding: 0px;\n clear: none;\n float: none;\n font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n text-align: left;\n font-size: 11px;\n}\n#flash:before {\n height: 575px;\n width: 987px;\n position: relative;\n top: -273px;\n left: 0px;\n z-index: 3;\n visibility: visible;\n margin: 0px;\n padding: 0px;\n clear: none;\n float: none;\n}\n#flash{\n height: 575px;\n width: 987px;\n position: absolute;\n top: 0px;\n left: 0px;\n z-index: 3;\n visibility: visible;\n margin: 0px;\n padding: 0px;\n clear: none;\n float: none;\n}\n#pannel{\n float: left;\n height: 360px;\n width: 687px;\n background-image: url(http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/html/pic/panel2.jpg);\n background-repeat: no-repeat;\n padding: 0px;\n position: relative;\n top: 80px;\n left: 150px;\n}\n#imageholder {\n float: left;\n height: 200px;\n width: 232px;\n padding: 0px;\n margin: 0px;\n background-color: #CCCCCC;\n position: relative;\n top: 4px;\n left: 29px;\n}\n#textfield {\n\tfloat: right;\n\tmargin: 0px;\n\tposition: relative;\n\ttop: 4px;\n\tright: 44px;\n\tpadding:5px; \n\toverflow:hidden;\n\theight: 256px;\n\twidth: 356px;\n\tborder: 1px solid #CCCCCC;\n\tfont-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n\tfont-size: 12px;\n\tcolor: #333333;\n}\n#headline{\n float: left;\n height: 40px;\n width: 610px;\n position: relative;\n top:  20px;\n left: 30px;\n font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n font-size: 12pt;\n font-weight: bolder;\n color: #B50000;\n}\n\n#wrapper {\n\twidth: 100%;\n \n.clear {\n clear:both;\n}\n-->\n</style>\n<!--[if IE]>\n<style type="text/css">\n\t#textfield {\n\t\ttop: 4px;\n\t\tright: 44px;\n\t\theight: 275px;\n\t\twidth: 365px;\n\t\toverflow:auto;\n\t}\n</style>\n<![endif]-->\n\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bitte ÃƒÂ¤ndern Sie im eigenen Interesse nichts an diesem Code! ++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Das kann massive Fehldarstellungen ihrer Auktion zur Folge haben! +++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Ihr Supreme Team +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- image1eWidth.intValue(): 235 --- image1eHeight.intValue(): 300 --&&--  height="200"\t -->\n\t\n<center>\n<div id="wrapper">\n<div id="doc">\n\t<div id="pannel">\n\t\t<div id="headline">Ed Hardy Herren Shirt Rock & Roll Weiss XXL Neu & OVP</div>\n\t\t<div class="clear"></div>\n\t\t<div id="imageholder"><table width="232" height="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" margin="0">\n\t\t  <tr align="center" valign="middle">\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t\t<img src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/13895964e.jpg" \n\t\t\t\t\t height="200" \n\t\t\t\t\t  border="0" align="middle"/>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t  </tr></table></div>\n\t\t<div id="textfield"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Zur Auktion steht ein Exklusives ED HARDY Herren T-Shirt in weiÃŸer Farbe, orginalverpackt und mit Etikett in der GrÃ¶ÃŸe XXL.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Das Shirt hat auf der Brust den Schriftzug &quot;Rock &amp; Roll Lives&quot; in Orange und Gelb besetzt mit Strass Steinen. </FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Auf dem RÃ¼cken ist wie auf dem Foto zu erkennen eine hochwertiger Aufdruck mit dem Schriftzug &quot;Beast of Burden&quot; in Gelb gedruckt.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Ich wÃ¼nsche Ihnen viel SpaÃŸ beim steigern und bitte beachten</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Sie auch meine anderen Angebote in Ebay!!</FONT></P> <br><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">100% Orginal</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Top QualitÃ¤t zu Top Preisen</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Hochwertigste Materialien</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Aufwendige Stickerein</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Top Verarbeitung</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">ExklusivitÃ¤t Pur</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P> <br><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Der Versand erfolgt mit der Deutschen Post. </FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Preise fÃ¼r EU LÃ¤nder auf Anfrage</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Falls mehrere Produkte gekauft werden fallen nur einmal Versandkosten an!!!! </FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="+0">Bitte per Mail vorher mitteilen</FONT></P> <br> <br><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Allgemeinen GeschÃ¤fts- und Lieferbedingungen (AGB)</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Diese AGBs gelten fÃ¼r alle Internet- Bestellungen und Auktionen:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Anwendungsbereich:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">FÃ¼r VertrÃ¤ge gelten ausschlieÃŸlich diese GeschÃ¤ftsbedingungen. Abweichenden Regelungen wird widersprochen. Andere als die hierin enthaltenen Regelungen werden nur mit unserer ausdrÃ¼cklichen schriftlichen Anerkennung wirksam. Die gelieferte Ware bleibt bis zur vollstÃ¤ndigen Bezahlung Eigentum des VerkÃ¤ufers.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Auktionsende:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Nach Ende der Auktion erhÃ¤lt der HÃ¶chst bietende von uns eine email mit der KaufbestÃ¤tigung und den AGB.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Bitte beachten Sie hierzu dringend, dass Ihre bei eBay hinterlegte email-Adresse aktuell ist, damit Sie sÃ¤mtliche Informationen zur Kaufabwicklung erhalten.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Zahlungsbedingungen:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Die Zahlung muss innerhalb von 7 Werktagen eingegangen sein. Ansonsten, stelle wir die Ware wieder ein und wir mÃ¼ssen dann leider eine Meldung bei eBay abgeben. Kann die Zahlung nicht rechtzeitig erfolgen, bitten wir um eine kurze Mail.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Lieferungs- und Versandbedingungen:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Lieferung der bestellten Ware nur nach vorheriger Bezahlung per Ãœberweisung, PayPal oder Nachname. Lieferung und Versand, nach Eingang des kompletten Betrages innerhalb des nÃ¤chsten Werktages. Versandkosten siehe Artikelbeschreibung. Bitte die gewÃ¼nschte Versandart angeben. Bei Mehrfach auktionen Sammellieferung mÃ¶glich.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Impressum</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Robert Wehowski</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Lange str. 72</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">76530 Baden-Baden</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">fashionticker@gmx.de</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Mit der Abgabe Ihres Gebotes geben Sie sich mit den GeschÃ¤ftsbedingungen einverstanden.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Widerrufsbelehrung</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Widerrufsrecht</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Sie kÃ¶nnen Ihre VertragserklÃ¤rung innerhalb von einem Monat ohne Angabe von GrÃ¼nden in Textform (z. B. Brief, Fax, E-Mail) oder - wenn Ihnen die Sache vor Fristablauf Ã¼berlassen wird - durch RÃ¼cksendung der Sache widerrufen. Die Frist beginnt nach Erhalt dieser Belehrung in Textform, jedoch nicht vor Eingang der Ware beim EmpfÃ¤nger (bei der wiederkehrenden Lieferung gleichartiger Waren nicht vor Eingang der ersten Teillieferung) und auch nicht vor ErfÃ¼llung unserer Informationspflichten gemÃ¤ÃŸ Â§ 312c Abs. 2 BGB in Verbindung mit Â§ 1 Abs. 1, 2 und 4 BGB-InfoV sowie unserer Pflichten gemÃ¤ÃŸ Â§ 312e Abs. 1 Satz 1 BGB in Verbindung mit Â§ 3 BGB-InfoV. Zur Wahrung der Widerrufsfrist genÃ¼gt die rechtzeitige Absendung des Widerrufs oder der Sache.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Der Widerruf ist zu richten an:</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Robert Wehowski</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Lange str. 72</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">76530 Baden-Baden</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">email: fashionticker@gmx.de</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Widerrufsfolgen</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Im Falle eines wirksamen Widerrufs sind die beiderseits empfangenen Leistungen zurÃ¼ckzugewÃ¤hren und ggf. gezogene Nutzungen (z. B. Zinsen) herauszugeben. KÃ¶nnen Sie uns die empfangene Leistung ganz oder teilweise nicht oder nur in verschlechtertem Zustand zurÃ¼ckgewÃ¤hren, mÃ¼ssen Sie uns insoweit ggf. Wertersatz leisten. Bei der Ãœberlassung von Sachen gilt dies nicht, wenn die Verschlechterung der Sache ausschlieÃŸlich auf deren PrÃ¼fung - wie sie Ihnen etwa im LadengeschÃ¤ft mÃ¶glich gewesen wÃ¤re - zurÃ¼ckzufÃ¼hren ist. FÃ¼r eine durch die bestimmungsgemÃ¤ÃŸe Ingebrauchnahme der Sache entstandene Verschlechterung mÃ¼ssen Sie keinen Wertersatz leisten.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">PaketversandfÃ¤hige Sachen sind auf unsere Gefahr zurÃ¼ckzusenden. Sie haben die Kosten der RÃ¼cksendung zu tragen, wenn die gelieferte Ware der bestellten entspricht und wenn der Preis der zurÃ¼ckzusendenden Sache einen Betrag von 40 Euro nicht Ã¼bersteigt oder wenn Sie bei einem hÃ¶heren Preis der Sache zum Zeitpunkt des Widerrufs noch nicht die Gegenleistung oder eine vertraglich vereinbarte Teilzahlung erbracht haben. Anderenfalls ist die RÃ¼cksendung fÃ¼r Sie kostenfrei. Die Frist beginnt fÃ¼r Sie mit der Absendung Ihrer WiderrufserklÃ¤rung oder der Sache, fÃ¼r uns mit deren Empfang.</FONT></P><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#000000" SIZE="-3">Ende der Widerrufsbelehrung</FONT></P><br><p style="font-size: 9px;" align="right">Diese Auktion wurde erstellt mit: <a href="http://www.supreme-auction.de">Supreme Auction</a> - die Software, Tool f&uuml;r die einfache Erstellung von professionellen Design Auktionen / Widgets.</p> </div>\n\t\t<div class="clear"><div style="visibility:hidden"><a href="http://www.supreme-auction.de">www.supreme-auction.de</a></div></div>\n \t</div>\n\t<div id="flash">\n\t\t<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">\n\t\tdocument.writeln('<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="987" height="575" align="middle"> <param name="WMODE" value="transparent" /> <PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="cPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/collector.swf&basePath=http%3A%2F%2Fstorage%2Esupremeauction%2Ecom%2Fflash%2F"> <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/startLoader2.swf"> <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high"> <PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF"> <embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/startLoader2.swf" FlashVars="cPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/collector.swf&basePath=http%3A%2F%2Fstorage%2Esupremeauction%2Ecom%2Fflash%2F" width="987" height="575" align="middle" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></OBJECT><BR>');\n\t\t</SCRIPT>\n\t\t<NOSCRIPT>\n\t\t<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="987" height="575" align="middle">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/startLoader2.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="menu" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="WMODE" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="FlashVars" value="cPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/collector.swf&basePath=http%3A%2F%2Fstorage%2Esupremeauction%2Ecom%2Fflash%2F" />\n\t\t\t<embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/startLoader2.swf" FlashVars="cPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/ebay2/10/49/76/10497654/collector.swf&basePath=http%3A%2F%2Fstorage%2Esupremeauction%2Ecom%2Fflash%2F" width="987" height="575" align="middle" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t</NOSCRIPT>\t\t\n\t</div>\n\t<div class="clear"></div>\n</div>\n<div class="clear"></div>\n\n<div id="doc2">\n<a href="http://www.supreme-auction.de">Supreme Auction: Kostenlose Startzeit, Bilder und Designs. Klick hier!</a>\n</div>\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bitte ÃƒÂ¤ndern Sie im eigenen Interesse nichts an diesem Code! ++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Das kann massive Fehldarstellungen ihrer Auktion zur Folge haben! +++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Ihr Supreme Team +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<br>\n<br>\n\n</div>\n</center>\n<span style="color:white">supremeauctiononlinesoftware.flash.auction_de</span>\n\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Bitte ÃƒÂ¤ndern Sie im eigenen Interesse nichts an diesem Code! ++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ Das kann massive Fehldarstellungen ihrer Auktion zur Folge haben! +++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Ihr Supreme Team +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->\n<!-- Supreme Automatic START -->\n<style type="text/css">\n<!--\n#automaticWidget {\n height: 252px;\n width: 989px;\n position: relative;\n}\n#automaticWidget .saline {\n\tline-height: 24px;\n\tbackground-color: #FFFFFF;\n\tfont-size: 11px;\n\tfont-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n\tcolor: #FFFFFF;\n\ttext-align: right;\n\tpadding-right: 5px;\n\t}\n\n-->\n</style>\n\n<center>\n\t<div id="automaticWidget">\n\t\t<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">\n\t\tdocument.writeln(\n\t\t\t'<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"  codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"  width="987" height="227" id="loader" align="middle">'+\n\t\t\t'<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> <param name="movie" value="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/loaderWide.swf" /> <param name="quality" value="high" /> <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />'+\n\t\t\t'<param name="FlashVars" value="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" />'+\n\t\t\t'<embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/loaderWide.swf" FlashVars="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" '+\n\t\t\t'quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="987" height="227" name="loader" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" '+\n\t\t\t'pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>');\n\t\t</SCRIPT>\n\t\t<NOSCRIPT>\n\t\t\t<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"\n\t\t\t        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"\n\t\t\t        width="987" height="227" id="loader" align="middle">\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="movie" value="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/loaderWide.swf" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="FlashVars"\n\t\t\t         value="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/loaderWide.swf"\n\t\t\t         FlashVars="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/"\n\t\t\t         quality="high"\n\t\t\t         bgcolor="#ffffff"\n\t\t\t         width="987" height="227" name="loader" align="middle"\n\t\t\t         allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"\n\t\t\t         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"\n\t\t\t         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />\n\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t</NOSCRIPT>\n\t\t<div class="saline">supremeauctiononlinesoftware.automatic.gallery <a href="http://www.supreme-auction.de">Supreme Auction:</a> <a href="http://www.supreme-automatic.de">Kostenlose eBay Tools! Klick hier!</a></div>\n\t</div>\t\n</center>\n<!-- Supreme Automatic END --><!-- Supreme Automatic START -->\n<style type="text/css">\n<!--\n#automaticWidget {\n\theight: 252px;\n\twidth: 989px;\n\tposition: relative;\n}\n#automaticWidget .saline {\n\tline-height: 24px;\n\tbackground-color: #FFFFFF;\n\tfont-size: 11px;\n\tfont-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n\tcolor: #FFFFFF;\n\ttext-align: right;\n\tpadding-right: 5px;\n\t}\n\n-->\n</style>\n\n<center>\n\t<div id="automaticWidget">\n\t\t<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">\n\t\t\t\n\t\tdocument.writeln(\n\t\t\t'<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"  codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"  width="987" height="135" id="loader" align="middle">'+\n\t\t\t'<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> <param name="movie" value="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/feedback.swf" /> <param name="quality" value="high" /> <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />'+\n\t\t\t'<param name="FlashVars" value="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" />'+\n\t\t\t'<embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/feedback.swf" FlashVars="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" '+\n\t\t\t'quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="987" height="135" name="loader" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" '+\n\t\t\t'pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>');\n\t\t</SCRIPT>\n\t\t\n\t\t<NOSCRIPT>\n\t\t\t<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"\n\t\t\t        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"\n\t\t\t        width="987" height="135" id="loader" align="middle">\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="movie" value="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/feedback.swf" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<param name="FlashVars"\n\t\t\t         value="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/" />\n\t\t\t  \t\t<embed src="http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/feedback.swf"\n\t\t\t         FlashVars="userPath=automatic/31/41/314162&rootPath=http://storage.supremeauction.com/flash/automatic2/"\n\t\t\t         quality="high"\n\t\t\t         bgcolor="#ffffff"\n\t\t\t         width="987" height="135" name="loader" align="middle"\n\t\t\t         allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"\n\t\t\t         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"\n\t\t\t         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />\n\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t</NOSCRIPT>\n\t\t<div class="saline">supremeauctiononlinesoftware.automatic.gallery <a href="http://www.supreme-auction.de">Supreme Auction:</a> <a href="http://www.supreme-automatic.de">Kostenlose eBay Tools! Klick hier!</a></div>\n\t</div>\t\n</center>\n<!-- Supreme Automatic END -->    77  Baden-Baden 1   0   1   0   -10006  1.00    0.00    1.00    0   0   1   77  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Where it should say Click here to continue it just shows:

```
1.00 
<\/OBJECT>
');\n\t\t<\/SCRIPT>\n\t\t
```

The other html records display fine

This is the code I am using to do so:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))
  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
else
  die("You should have a 'cmd' parameter in your URL");
 $pk = $_GET["pk"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","x","geheim");
if(!$con)
{
die('Connection failed because of' .mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ebay",$con);
if($cmd=="GetAuctionData")
{
$sql="SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
$sql2="SELECT ARTICLE_DESC FROM Auctions WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";
$htmlset = mysql_query($sql2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($htmlset);


// <p><strong>Category</strong></p> ".$row['CATEGORY']."

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div id='leftlayer'>
  <strong>Article Number</strong> ".$row['ARTICLE_NO']."
    <p><strong>Article Name</strong></p> ".$row['ARTICLE_NAME']."
    <p><strong>Subtitle</strong></p> ".$row['SUBTITLE']."
    <p><strong>Username</strong></p> ".$row['USERNAME']."
    <p><strong>Total Selling</strong></p> ".$row['QUANT_TOTAL']."
    <p><strong>Total Sold</strong></p> ".$row['QUANT_SOLD']."

    <p><strong>Highest Bidder</strong></p> ".$row['BEST_BIDDER_ID']."
  </div>
<div class='leftlayer2'>
  <strong>Current Bid</strong> ".$row['CURRENT_BID']."
  <p><strong>Start Price</strong></p> ".$row['START_PRICE']."
  <p><strong>Buyitnow Price</strong></p> ".$row['BUYITNOW_PRICE']."
  <p><strong>Bid Count</strong></p> ".$row['BID_COUNT']."
  <p><strong>Start Date</strong></p> ".$row['ACCESSSTARTS']."
  <p><strong>End Date</strong></p> ".$row['ACCESSENDS']."
  <p><strong>Original End</strong></p> ".$row['ACCESSORIGIN_END']."
  <p><strong>Auction Type</strong></p> ".$row['AUCTION_TYPE']."
</div>
<div class='leftlayer2'>
  <strong>Private Auction</strong></p> ".$row['PRIVATE_AUCTION']."
  <p><strong>Paypal Accepted</strong></p> ".$row['PAYPAL_ACCEPT']."
  <p><strong>Auction Watched</strong></p> ".$row['WATCH']."
  <p><strong>Finished</strong></p> ".$row['FINISHED']."

  <p><strong>Location</strong></p> ".$row['LOCATION']."
  <p><strong>Conditions</strong></p> ".$row['CONDITIONS']."
</div>
<div class='leftlayer2'>
  <strong>Auction Revised</strong></p> ".$row['REVISED']."
  <p><strong>Cancelled</strong></p> ".$row['PRE_TERMINATED']."
  <p><strong>Shipping to</strong></p> ".$row['SHIPPING_TO']."
  <p><strong>Fee Insertion</strong></p> ".$row['FEE_INSERTION']."
  <p><strong>Fee Final</strong></p> ".$row['FEE_FINAL']."
  <p><strong>Fee Listing</strong></p> ".$row['FEE_LISTING']."
  <p><a href='#' onclick='makewindows(" . json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"]) . "); return false;'>Click for full description </a></p>
</div>";
$lastImg = $row['PIC_URL'];
echo "<div id='rightlayer'>Picture Picture
<img src='".$lastImg."'>
</div>";

}

}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me - what's the problem?

Comment: "It seemingly imports fine, however when attempting to display one of the fields containing html." (Not a sentence. Please make more sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you need to escape all values, that you embed into HTML.

All your `$row['WHATEVER']` should be [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)`($row['WHATEVER'])`. Also, your json data may contain quotes, so that should additionally be escaped:

```
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"]), ENT_QUOTES)
```

On a side note, your code is vulnerable to mysql injection. You need to escape any values, that you embed into SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($pk) . "'";
```

(See the pattern there? **You need to escape any values, that you embed into XXX**, where XXX is some sort of code.)